# Parse HTML, set datas to variables

Tags: python

How can I get phone, fax and address from my HTML source using Python? I need to set it to variables.

```
<h2>My name</h2>
<img src="images/logos/" style="float:right" />
<p>Adress  37/41 Portbell</p>
<p>P.O.Box 12339, Kampala</p>
<p>Tel: +41 414220702</p>
<p>Fax: +41 414220929</p>
```

I can't use pyquery in this case :(

Comment: Do you know that the HTML will always be formatted the same way?

Comment: @senshin Yes, will always formatted the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) for HTML parsing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = ... # your html goes here
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

telephone_p = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Tel:'))
telephone = telephone_p[0].replace('Tel:', '').strip()
fax_p = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Fax:'))
fax = fax_p[0].replace('Fax:', '').strip()
address_ps = soup.find_all('p')[:2]
address = '\n'.join([p.text for p in address_ps])

print(telephone)
print(fax)
print(address)
```

Result:

```
+41 414220702
+41 414220929
Adress  37/41 Portbell
P.O.Box 12339, Kampala
```

---

Alternative solution, using only the standard library:

```
import re

html = ... # your html goes here

telephone = re.search('Tel: ([+\d\s]+)', html).groups()[0]
fax = re.search('Fax: ([+\d\s]+)', html).groups()[0]
paragraphs = [line for line in html.split('\n') if line.startswith('<p>')]
address = '\n'.join([p.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '')
                     for p in paragraphs[0:2]])

print(telephone)
print(fax)
print(address)
```

Result: same as above.

---

These solutions are fragile, and will break (possibly spectacularly) if the format of your HTML changes.